# sp_Blitz Findings: SQL Server Last Restart is an hour before Server Last Restart

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz

Result of sp_Blitz:
Finding = “Server Last Restart” ; Details = “Feb 11 2017 5:48AM”
Finding = “SQL Server Last Restart” ; Details = “Feb 11 2017 4:48AM”

SQL Server Last Restart is the tempdb create_date
Server Last Restart is the ms_ticks

I find the results odd because, SQL Server Started an hour before Server Restart?
[image]
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Exactly 1 hour... I wonder if this is due to Daylight Saving Time?

Comment: Is your server in a time zone that observes Daylight Saving Time? Looks like the Server Last Restart has been adjusted for the "current" DST timezone, but the SQL Server Last Restart is in the unadjusted non-DST timezone.

Comment: The Server is in Central Time. However, I am wondering how can SQL Server read different time than Windows time !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would 'suggest' that when the server was restarted (and Sql Server was also restarted) back on February 11, 2017, the current Windows time, which was Standard time and not Daylight Saving time, was *captured* as the Creation Date of TEMPDB (and that is what SP_Blitz uses to determine Sql Server restart time).

Now, you are running SP_Blitz **AFTER** the change to Daylight Saving time and sys.dm_os_sys_info (which is used by SP_Blitz to report Server Last Restart and appears to be Daylight Saving time aware) is affected by the time change, thus making it '*look*' like the server started AFTER Sql Server.